# State Variable not displaying in Input field when using React-Hook-Form in a Wizard Form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, react-state-management

Just want to preface this by saying I know this is an edge case, but I want to be able to dynamically build a form by bringing in several instances of field "shapes" as I call them. The idea is that each row of the form would consist of a mixture of fields (all with labels), maybe two free-form fields and a drop down, maybe a single multiline text box, maybe three free-form fields.
Side note: I'm using react-hook-form and little-state-machine for this.

To do this I've turned repeated chunks of HTML, such as this:

```
<div>
  <div>
    <label for="first_name">First name</label>
    <input {...register("firstName")} defaultValue={state.firstName}
            type="text" id="first_name"placeholder="John" required />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="middleName">Middle name</label>
    <input {...register("middleName")} defaultValue={state.middleName}
           type="text" id="middleName" placeholder="Adams" />
  </div>
  <div>
    <label for="last_name">Last name</label>
    <input {...register("lastName")} defaultValue={state.lastName}
           type="text" id="last_name" placeholder="Doe" required />
  </div>
</div>
```

..into Class Components that I pass in all the props I need, like this:

```
<Ff3 in1={"first_name"} in1Label={"First name"} inPH1={"John"}
     in2={"middleName"} in2Label={"Middle name"} inPH2={"Adams"}
     in3={"last_name"} in3Label={"Last name"}  inPH3={"Doe"}
     regi={register}
   />
```

Inside Ff3 it looks a lot like the original HTML chunk except I plug in the props.

```
<div>
  <label for={this.props.in1}>{this.props.in1Label}</label>
  <input {...this.props.regi(this.props.in1)}
         type="text" id={this.props.in1} placeholder={this.props.inPH1} />
</div>
```

Now to the crux of the problem. Each step/page of my Wizard is wrapped in a form tag which triggers the State update on a button click (e.g. the 'Next' button). When I click the Next button on a page that uses this Ff3 component I can see that the value entered IS being stored in the state (by looking at the session storage in my dev console) but if I navigate back to that same Wizard step the value which is correctly in the State isn't being displayed in the Input field.
On Wizard Pages where I'm not using these Class Components (opting for the div->label->input original version) I can navigate away and to the page and it correctly displays the value stored in State.
The easy solution is obviously "Stop using the Class Component" but my goal is to be able to parse a JSON file and dynamically build a form that is all wired up and ready to go. Ambitious? Of course, but we didn't land on the moon by taking the easy route.

What I tried previously:
At first my Ff3 component was a Functional Component, but it wasn't updating the State with the value being entered on the Input field. I let my subconscious work the problem over night and decided to try a Class Component to get around this problem (which it did) only to present me with a new problem.

Comment: Update: I've found that I was missing the "defaultValue" property in my input, but now I'm faced with being unable to access the state variable dynamically. If I pass the state in to my Class component add this: defaultValue=this.props.state.firstName it'll work, but I want to be able to pass it generically, e.g. defaultValue=this.props.state.(in1) (which would resolve to whatever the value of the Prop was) Help still needed

Comment: Update 2, for my own future self, I can access the state dynamically using defaultValue={this.props.state[this.props.in1]}

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I am missing the defaultValue property in my inputs. That property should point to the State variable in which the value is stored by dynamically accessing the state using the passed in ID a la:

```html
<input {...this.props.regi(this.props.in1)} defaultValue={this.props.state[this.props.in1]}
                    type="text" id={this.props.in1} placeholder={this.props.inPH1} />
```